# Getting User store segfault error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am receiving the error "User store segfault `@ 0x000000007feff598`" for a large convolution operation. 
I have defined the resultant array as

```
        int t3_isize = 0;
        int t3_irowcount = 0;
        t3_irowcount=atoi(argv[2]);
        t3_isize = atoi(argv[3]);
        int iarray_size = t3_isize*t3_irowcount;

        uint64_t t_result[iarray_size];
```

I noticed that if the array size is less than `2^16 - 1`, the operation doesn't fail, but for the array size `2^16` or higher, I get the segfault error.

Any idea why this is happening? And how can i rectify this?

Comment: What platform are you using, and are you trying to put that array on the stack?

Comment: Is this array global or on the stack?

Comment: 8 * 65536 = 524288 bytes for that array. I smell a stack overrun. You may do well to [**read this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap#79936), as it is easily one of the very best posted on SO.

Comment: Did you mean **less than** ` 2^16 - 1` just to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Yes sorry about that typo.

Comment: `std::cout << iarray_size << std::endl;` I'm curious what that says right *before* your array/vector sizing is done, *exactly* as I showed. And you may want to mention the platform and tools you're using, as well as a debugger walk through this code, as using a `std::vector<int> t_result(iarray_size);` will occupy literally 12-bytes on a normal stack. I don't supposed you're returning this "thing" from a function, are you? (the name somewhat hints to that).

Comment: I am on 
Linux XXXXXXXX 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun May 6 04:00:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

std::cout << iarray_size << std::endl; prints 90000, which is the expected array size.

Answer (score 0):

> “I noticed that if the array size is greater than 2^16 - 1, the operation doesn't fail, but for the array size 2^16 or higher, I get the segfault error”

↑ Seems a bit self-contradictory.

But probably you're just allocating a too large array on the stack. Using dynamic memory allocation (e.g., just switch to using **`std::vector`**) you avoid that problem. For example:

```
std::vector<uint64_t> t_result(iarray_size);
```

---

In passing, I would ditch the Hungarian notation-like prefixes. For example, `t_` reads like this is a type. The time for Hungarian notation was late 1980's, and its purpose was to support Microsoft's Programmer's Workbench, a now dicontinued (for very long) product.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. If the size is less than 2^16 -1, everything is fine

Comment: I am receiving the same error even with dynamic memory allocation as you suggested.

Comment: try to place a `return` right after the declaration of the vector. if it doesn't crash then, then the problem must be in following code. and so on. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably declaring too large of an array for the stack.  2<sup>16</sup> elements of 8 bytes each is quite a lot (512K bytes).

If you just need static allocation, move the array to file scope.

Otherwise, consider using `std::vector`, which will allocate storage from the heap and manage it for you.

Comment: How is `iarray_size` declared?  And are you remembering to either declare your `vector` with the desired initial size, or at least calling `resize()` on it?

Comment: iarray_size is being calculated in the previous line and does not change after that.        
I am declaring the vector like this:
        std::vector<uint64_t> t_result(iarray_size);

Comment: @user3039976 Is `iarray_size` at least of type `int` or larger?  Can you edit your question to show that calculation, also?

Comment: @user3039976 :  Hmmm, that looks pretty innocuous.  The actual fault you're getting (the store) must be further down when you try to write something to this.  The 2^16 boundary makes it feel weird, like something got truncated to a `short` or something...  but I don't see anything immediately that jumps out.

Answer (score 0):

Using malloc() solved the issue.

```
            uint64_t* t_result = (uint64_t*) malloc(sizeof(uint64_t)*iarray_size);
```